# Using Marshal.Copy to copy data acquired from android camera using arcore in extra thread

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, marshalling

I'm trying to copy the data I get from Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes() into an manages byte array. But this is time consuming and i want to make my android app run fluently so i wanted to do this in an extra thread. But depending on the way I'm copying the data unity crashes, or everything after Marshal.ReadByte() isn't executed anymore without any error message.

I've tried already using different methods of Marshal but none did work. Also I tried using it inside an extra thread and outside. Outside the code with ReadByte (with copy I didn't tried) worked without any problems.

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (!SavingImage)
    {
        using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
        {
            if (image.IsAvailable)
            {
                SavingImage = true;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SaveImageAndFreeIt), image);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void SaveImageAndFreeIt(object state)
{
    CameraImageBytes image = (CameraImageBytes)state;
    CalcGrayscaleImage(image.Y);
    SavingImage = false;

    image.Release();
}

private void CalcGrayscaleImage(IntPtr data)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            int pos = y * Width + x;
            float Yvalue = Marshal.ReadByte(data, pos);
            Yvalue /= 255.0f;

            Color c = Pixels[pos];
            c.r = Yvalue;
            c.g = Yvalue;
            c.b = Yvalue;
            Pixels[pos] = c;
        }
    }
    SavingImage = false;
}
```

I expected that this would write the imagedata as Color32 into the Pixels array. But with some output I found out that nothing after float Yvalue = Marshal.ReadByte(data, pos); is executed but I don't get any error message.

```cs
private void CalcGrayscaleImage(IntPtr data)
{
    byte[] bData = new byte[Width * Height];
    Marshal.Copy(data, bData, 0, Width * Height);
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            int pos = y * Width + x;
            float Yvalue = bData[pos];
            Yvalue /= 255.0f;

            Color c = Pixels[pos];
            c.r = Yvalue;
            c.g = Yvalue;
            c.b = Yvalue;
            Pixels[pos] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second version that I tried and i don't understand why this is not working. Executing this i get the Message and unity crashes completely: [Errormessage after using Marshal.Copy()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtpXV.png)

Comment: You know that with your code `image` is prolly diposed before hits `SaveImageAndFreeIt` ?

Comment: could you explain to me why? because I don't see how that could happen? And if so can i somehow prevent arcore to do it? that might be then the  whole problem
edit:
I see it now. thanks for the comment. I have to have a look at the using directive...